# Django Userena Change default messages

Tags: python, django, message, django-userena

i want to change the messages like 'You have been signed out. Till we meet again.'

Is there any way to change it without copying the directory in the project?
I've installed userena with pip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with userena, but it seems they have the templates you want to change in templates/userena/. Creating a folder named "userena" and overriding the files you want should be enough to achieve what you want. In your case you would want to override [signout.html](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/templates/userena/signout.html)

Comment: Yes, i've already override the template. But the messages are in the translations files.

Comment: You need to define your locale dir and run makemessages. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#makemessages